# Status code for POST and PUT fails through pom.xml mvn test

Tags: maven, post, put, rest-assured

When I am running the testng.xml file through pom.xml, my rest-assured test case fails with error statusCode is null for POST and PUT APIs. For GET, it works fine.

> Time elapsed: 0.066 sec  <<< FAILURE! java.lang.NullPointerException

But the same works fine when I run the test cases individually or via testng.xml.

This is the test case -

```
public class CreateUser extends TestBase{

static Response response;

    @Test(priority=0, description="Create the user")
    public void createUser(){

        TestModelPojo testModel = new TestModelPojo();

        Primary prim = new Primary();
        prim.setFirstname(firstName);

        testModel.setPrimary(prim);
        testModel.setEmail(eMail);


    response = SerenityRest.given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .log()
                .all()
                .when()
                .body(testModel)
                .post("/customer/register")
                .then()
                .extract().response();

    }

    @Test(priority=1, description="Generate the status code as 201")
    public void getStatusCode() throws InterruptedException {   
        response.then().log().all().statusCode(201);
    }

}
```

TestBase class -

```
public class TestBase {

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        RestAssured.baseURI  = "http://restapi.demoqa.com";
    }

}
```

What could be the possible reason behind that?

```
<plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <source>1.8</source>
               <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
```

testng.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" verbose="2">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test" preserve-order="true">
     <classes>
      <class name="com.demo.CreateUser"/>
    </classes>  

  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Without showing the code its hard to find out what is wrong. Please edit your question and add your test code.

Comment: Updated the questions. The problem is the response variable becomes null in getStatusCode method, when i trigger from pom.xml.. so, it may be the sequence problem with maven-surefire-plugin. but via testng.xml surefire is not required. so it runs my test case. Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: There's variable with name `response` present in both test methods, but i don't see where it is initialized. Where do you initialize it?

Comment: In the class itself. I have not mentioned it. Let me update the question.

Comment: Actually response becomes null when it moves to next method, which is getStatusCode() through pom.xml. But directly hitting from testng.xml works fine.So, it may be the problem with maven-surefire-plugin. it has some different approach to run any tests.